# How to store entities with many to many relationships using AutoMapper and EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

I have three entities, `Product`, `Feature` and `ProductFeature`. `ProductFeature` is a join table, maintaining a list of both entities.

```
public class Product
{
    public ICollection<ProductFeature> ProductFeatures { get; set; }
}

public class Feature
{
    public ICollection<ProductFeature> ProductFeatures { get; set; }
}

public class ProductFeature
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public Feature Feature { get; set; }
}
```

I want to hide the relation table in the DTO and represent the features by using a simple colleciton, like so:

```
public class ProductDTO
{
    public ICollection<Feature> Features { get; set; }
}
```

I am using AutoMapper in order to perform the mapping from my DTO to my entity:

```
public class ProductProfile : Profile
{
    public ProductProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Product, ProductDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Feature, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProductFeature.Select(y => y.Feature).ToList()));
        CreateMap<ProductDTO, Product>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProductName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductFeatures, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Features))
            .AfterMap((src, dest) =>{
                foreach(var pf in dest.ProductFeatures)
                {
                    pf.ProductId = src.Id;
                }
            });
        CreateMap<Feature, ProductFeature>()
            .ForMember(dest=>dest.FeatureId,opt=>opt.MapFrom(src=>src.Id))
            .ForMember(dest=>dest.Feature,opt=>opt.MapFrom(src=>src));
    }
}
```

If I want to add new `Products`, I have to map the `ProductDTO` to `Product` and manually iterate over the child object `Feature`, in order to detect if the child entity is already present in the context or not and then create a new entity including the relations or update the existing one.

If my entities have multiple many-to-many relations, my methods get very long. Is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection.EFCore